# linking row with a column in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to get a resultset using two tables

1. Trail Balance
2. Aging

the structure of the tables are

**Aging**

```
loc    |    glAcct    |    Amount
-----------------------------------
1013   |     1101     |    200
-----------------------------------
1211   |     1102     |    300
-----------------------------------
```

**Trial Balance**

```
loc   |    g1101    |   g1102
------------------------------
1013  |     20      |    30
------------------------------
1211  |     10      |    40
-----------------------------
```

now what i am trying to do is to match the rows with the columns 
what i want now is

```
loc   |   glAcct    |    agigingAmount |  Trialbalance Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------
1013  |     1101    |      200         |        20
--------------------------------------------------------------
1211  |     1102    |      300         |        40
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

i have tried case statements like

```
select ag.loc,ag.glAcct,
case
   when ag.glAcct = '1101' then select g1101 from trialbalance 
   when ag.glAcct = '1102' then select gl101 from trialbalance 
end  

 from trialbalance tb,Aging ag where ag.loc = tb.loc
```

but its not working.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ag.loc,
ag.glAcct, 
ag.Amount AS agigingAmount,
TrialbalanceAmount=
CASE ag.glAcct
   WHEN '1101' THEN tb.g1101
   WHEN '1102' THEN tb.g1102
END
FROM Aging ag,trialbalance tb 
WHERE ag.loc = tb.loc;
```

[Here is a working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21ef2/1/0)

Comment: Note: The example is in SQL SERVER 2008 R2 as i got only this to demonstrate the working of code online.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there:

```
SELECT ag.loc, ag.glAcct, ag.Amount AS agigingAmount
CASE ag.glAcct
   WHEN '1101' THEN tb.g1101
   WHEN '1102' THEN tb.g1102
END AS [Trialbalance Amount]
FROM Aging ag
INNER JOIN trialbalance tb on ag.loc = tb.loc
```

Comment: +1 for the INNER JOIN.  I would also recommend to the Op to 'fix' (normalise) the data layout.  But I'm on my phone and writing an example would be taxing :)

Comment: @Dems Yes, agreed about normalization, but I'm on my phone now too :)

Comment: @Dems I did not created the database so its not in my hands. When I was given the problem the same thing came in my mind too..but thanks for your valuable comment. I hope they let me correct the database.